# Integrating order effects into a logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic

Simple question -- how does one implement order effects of a dependent variables in a logistic regression.  For example, let's say someone is trying to predict someone's mood (happy or sad) based on the weather (rain or shine).  One would anticipate that the order in which someone experiences the weather would impact their mood (e.g sunny, sunny, rain is different than sunny, rain, sunny).  How does one account for this -- the only thing I can think of is dummy coding where the dependent variables occurs in the "chain".  Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell us some more details & context? Do you have data, or is this a question about experimental design? Maybe a Markov model?